# JSON decoding error: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[object Object]')

Tags: rest, openapi-generator, jsondecodeerror

Hi I'm using openApiGenerator=7.1.0 with SpringBoot=3.1.5

I just stared learning RESt API. I'm trying to invoke my PATCH method when I add pet to it's owner.
While doing this I get

message:
JSON decoding error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.infrastructure.petstore.model.Pet$StatusEnum`, problem: Unexpected value 'string'
cause:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.infrastructure.petstore.model.Pet$StatusEnum`, problem: Unexpected value 'string' at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 126] (through reference chain: com.example.infrastructure.petstore.model.Pet["status"])

I'm using generated classes created by openApiGenerator library

```
package com.example.infrastructure.petstore;

import com.example.controller.dao.PetDAO;
import com.example.infrastructure.petstore.api.PetApi;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PetClientImpl implements PetDAO {

    private final PetApi petApi;
    private final PetMapper petMapper;

    @Override
    public Optional<Pet> getPet(Long petId) {

        try {
            // available is only to put breakpoint and see in debugger
            final var available
                    = petApi.findPetsByStatusWithHttpInfo("available")
                    .block()
                    .getBody();
            return Optional.ofNullable(petApi.getPetById(petId).block())
                    .map(petMapper::map);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}


this is generated class Pet:
```

```
/*
 * Swagger Petstore - OpenAPI 3.0
 * This is a sample Pet Store Server based on the OpenAPI 3.0 specification.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io). In the third iteration of the pet store, we've switched to the design first approach! You can now help us improve the API whether it's by making changes to the definition itself or to the code. That way, with time, we can improve the API in general, and expose some of the new features in OAS3.  Some useful links: - [The Pet Store repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore) - [The source API definition for the Pet Store](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml)
 *
 * The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0.17
 * Contact: apiteam@swagger.io
 *
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */


package com.example.infrastructure.petstore.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.example.infrastructure.petstore.model.Category;
import com.example.infrastructure.petstore.model.Tag;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

/**
 * Pet
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  Pet.JSON_PROPERTY_ID,
  Pet.JSON_PROPERTY_NAME,
  Pet.JSON_PROPERTY_CATEGORY,
  Pet.JSON_PROPERTY_PHOTO_URLS,
  Pet.JSON_PROPERTY_TAGS,
  Pet.JSON_PROPERTY_STATUS
})
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2023-11-27T13:15:44.475018+01:00[Europe/Warsaw]")
public class Pet implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_ID = "id";
  private Long id;

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_NAME = "name";
  private String name;

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_CATEGORY = "category";
  private Category category;

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_PHOTO_URLS = "photoUrls";
  private List<String> photoUrls = new ArrayList<>();

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_TAGS = "tags";
  private List<Tag> tags;

  /**
   * pet status in the store
   */
  public enum StatusEnum {
    AVAILABLE("available"),
    
    PENDING("pending"),
    
    SOLD("sold");

    private String value;

    StatusEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static StatusEnum fromValue(String value) {
      for (StatusEnum b : StatusEnum.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
  }

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_STATUS = "status";
  private StatusEnum status;

  public Pet() {
  }

  public Pet id(Long id) {
    
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get id
   * @return id
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_ID)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }


  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_ID)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }


  public Pet name(String name) {
    
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nonnull
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }


  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }


  public Pet category(Category category) {
    
    this.category = category;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get category
   * @return category
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_CATEGORY)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
  }


  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_CATEGORY)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
  public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
  }


  public Pet photoUrls(List<String> photoUrls) {
    
    this.photoUrls = photoUrls;
    return this;
  }

  public Pet addPhotoUrlsItem(String photoUrlsItem) {
    if (this.photoUrls == null) {
      this.photoUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.photoUrls.add(photoUrlsItem);
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get photoUrls
   * @return photoUrls
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nonnull
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_PHOTO_URLS)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)

  public List<String> getPhotoUrls() {
    return photoUrls;
  }


  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_PHOTO_URLS)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  public void setPhotoUrls(List<String> photoUrls) {
    this.photoUrls = photoUrls;
  }


  public Pet tags(List<Tag> tags) {
    
    this.tags = tags;
    return this;
  }

  public Pet addTagsItem(Tag tagsItem) {
    if (this.tags == null) {
      this.tags = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.tags.add(tagsItem);
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get tags
   * @return tags
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_TAGS)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
  }


  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_TAGS)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
  public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }


  public Pet status(StatusEnum status) {
    
    this.status = status;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * pet status in the store
   * @return status
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_STATUS)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public StatusEnum getStatus() {
    return status;
  }


  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_STATUS)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
  public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Pet pet = (Pet) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, pet.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.name, pet.name) &&
        Objects.equals(this.category, pet.category) &&
        Objects.equals(this.photoUrls, pet.photoUrls) &&
        Objects.equals(this.tags, pet.tags) &&
        Objects.equals(this.status, pet.status);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, name, category, photoUrls, tags, status);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Pet {\n");
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    category: ").append(toIndentedString(category)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    photoUrls: ").append(toIndentedString(photoUrls)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    tags: ").append(toIndentedString(tags)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    status: ").append(toIndentedString(status)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }

}
```

My expectation were that, the Pet will be created, in my database there will be Pet assign to it's Owner and thats it